Adding a text box to an image in R / R Quarto
I am trying to add a text box to an image, like on the picture below (done in paint).
I know that I can use image_annotate from the magick package, but it seems to allow me only to add text (in a single line). I am looking to add a text box such that the text stays within the text box. Any ideas?


Just add a new line character "\n" where you want a line break in your text as follows:  "This is my\nfirst picture!"
